# Known issues for iOS modularized approach?

Tags: ios, swift3, ios10, ios-frameworks

We've a classic iOS application which was developed using objective-c and it has lot of features. The same features has been used for other similar apps as well.

Now we've plan to rewamp the entite application. One of the approach to reduce the development work,  we've plan to modularize features as framework re-using the same objective-c code, so that all applicaiton can use the framework and compile time will be less.

Also as part of rewamp, we will be using iOS 10 and swift3.

Please kindly share me your ideas/feedback, what are issues will be popup or any limitaion to do this approach.

Appreciate your help!

Thanks,
Srini

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just pack it as cocoapods and deploy into your company git is the fastest way i suppose, packing into framework is also fine but it have many boilerplate thing like cant run on either device or simulator, and if using fat framework then need to extract the simulator part out when you archive, or have to use embed framework if they are depent on each other,.... its just pretty annoying